# "once in a blue moon" and "rarely"

Tags: subject-auxiliary-inversion, negative-inversion

Does "once in a blue moon," an expression that means "very rarely," also require inversion?

1. Rarely does he work at night.
2. He rarely works at night.
3. Once in a blue moon does he work at night.
4. Once in a blue moon he works at night.

Answer (score 1):

Both

> Rarely, he works at night

and

> Once in a blue moon, he works at night.

are grammatical.  Inversion is not required.

Answer (score 1):

"Rarely" does not always require inversion. For instance, one can say "He rarely works at night". "Once in a blue moon" does not take inversion by itself, but you can use inversion if you also include "only": "Only once in a blue moon does he work at night".

Comment: You said " 'Rarely' does not always require inversion." What if "rarely" is at the beginning of a sentence?